# Using DateTimePicker but value deleted

Tags: datetimepicker

I am using the Datetimepicker plugin.

when i press the backspace, a single digit should delete but for me the complete date and time gets deleted and replaced with --/--/------:--

Comment: if i select the date, 21/12/1987 12:45

 if i want to replace the time as 11:45, i press the backspace, then it is replaced with --/--/------:--

Comment: could you paste your screenshot here and provide more infor regarding which language you use.

Comment: i am using Javascript, Jquery, JSP , JAVA and  plugin is datetimepicker.js. if you need any other specific clarification let me know

Comment: pls chk this code, http://code.runnable.com/VuZQkwOHJ79a5K4V/output,   i selected the date and if i press the backspace, digit by digit is getting deleted. but in my application, all the digits are deleted and replaced with hyphens. this is my problem.

Comment: plz paste your tried code, specified weblink doesn't work

Comment: http://web-c213fda1-1d2e-4338-8a45-3ebf51d37b3e.runnablecodesnippets.com/

Comment: function dateTimePickerField(obj)
        {
            $('#'+obj).datetimepicker();
        }